# Retrieving distance matrix from kknn model

Tags: r, knn, mlr

Is it possible to retrieve the distance matrix from the `kknn` model when using `mlr` package in R and cross validation?

```
library("mlr")

data(iris)

task = makeClassifTask(data = iris, target = "Species")

lnr = makeLearner(
  cl = "classif.kknn",
  predict.type = "prob",
  k = 5,
  kernel = "gaussian",
  scale = TRUE
)

cv = crossval(
  learner = lnr,
  task = task,
  iters = 4,
  stratify = TRUE,
  measures = acc,
  show.info = FALSE,
  model = TRUE
)

str(cv$models[1])
```

I can't see anything related in `cv$models` or `cv$pred`.

Comment: Also,  your code uses `task = task` but you do not show us how you generated `task`.  Is the data hidden in `task`?

Comment: Thanky you for the feedback. I just wanted to sketch out the `crossval` function, because `mlr` is highly standardized. As a result, the data import step is always the same, hence, this is why it is omitted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `crossval` is a `ResampleResult`, which contains the models fitted in the individual iterations in the `$models` member (note that this is a list). The models are the objects returned by the underlying learner, so in each model there should be a member `$D$` that contains the distance matrix.

See [the tutorial](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/resample/index.html) for more information.

Edit: In this particular case, you don't get the learner models in the usual place because `kknn` is a (model-less) clusterer and the `kknn` function doesn't actually get called by `mlr` until you `predict`. The "model" returned by `train` is just the training data (with a few additional bits).

The `predict` function returns just the predictions and not the model, so unfortunately in this particular case you can't get to the distance matrices directly. However, you can get the learner model from `mlr` and call `kknn` on that to get the distance matrices:

```
 kknn(getTaskFormula(cv$models[[1]]$task.desc),
  train = cv$models[[1]]$learner.model$data,
  test = iris)$D
```

Comment: Thank you, Lars. I already checked `str(cv$models[1])`, but I don't see a member `$D` in the list. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post your complete code + data that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: Thank you very much, Lars! Though, it's a bit unfortunate that you can't directly access the distance matrix. I will see what I can do about it.

Comment: The underlying issue is that the distance matrix only becomes available when the test data is given. So there's no way to get it in the train function, and for predict mlr doesn't have a concept of more than just predictions being returned. You can have a look at the source code though (it's only a few lines for predict) and adapt accordingly for a special function you can use in your case.